# Porting windows phone 8.0 apps to windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a project in Windows Phone 8.0 SDK for the last year or so. Now that Windows Phone 8.1 SDK is out I am trying to port my application to 8.1 SDK.

Currently, I have targeted my application which was built in 8.0 to 8.1. It works fine. But there are certain things which I am curious to know more are the about the namespace changes.

So now all the windows 8.1 and windows phone 8.1 apps fall under the windows store apps, there are certain namespace that are missing. For example, the `System.IO.IsolatedStorage` namespace does not exist in the 8.1 SDK. But there exists `Windows.Storage` namespace which can serve the same purpose.

Here's where it gets really interesting,

I have a solution with 10 projects built in 8.0 originally, and targeted to 8.1. `System.IO.IsolatedStorage` namespace still works and `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media` namespace still works. But when I create a new project in the same solution, I don't get these namespace.

I get the point that the original project was built in 8.0 and that's why I am able to see the earlier namespaces. But the problem arises when I would like to use the isolated storage data in the 8.1 SDK.

I am assuming that the solution would be to change each and every namespace to Windows.Storage instead of System.IO.IsolatedStorage. This is going to be a tedious process as the application we have here is quite a big application.

Am I missing anything here? What is the best practice?

Comment: Create your new projects targeting 8.0 then switch them after-the-fact to 8.1?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that some of them targetted "Windows Phone 8.0 and up" and some targetted "Windows Phone 8.1". See if there is an option to create a new project which targets "Windows Phone 8.0 and up".

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you upgrading to Silverlight 8.1, or to a Universal App (Windows Runtime)

Comment: I am not working on universal apps. I am working on windows phone 8.1 only.

Comment: @golldy According to your question, you're working on Universal Apps. There's no such thing as "Windows Phone 8.1 only" apps, the platform supports both Silverlight and Windows Runtime as two different application types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But when I create a new project in the same solution, I don't get these namespace.

Sounds like you're creating a Windows Runtime project in your solution, and your existing solutions are Silverlight 8.1 solutions.

You need to make sure you pick a project type that includes "Silverlight".

Comment: Not really.. System.IO.IsolatedStorage does not exist for windows phone 8.1 projects.

Comment: @golldy Wrong. It exists for Silverlight 8.1 projects, but not Windows Runtime projects.

Comment: Ah. you are completely right. I was totally missing out on the Silverlight 8.1 projects. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I do not understand why MSFT did this!